# Converting non-xml to xml or SOAP using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, soap

I have to convert response like this to

```
Data received successfully to XML
```

to XML or SOAP

**This XML output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>Data received successfully</response>
```

**Or SOAP**

Both of them will work

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP:Header/>
    <SOAP:Body>
    <response>Data received successfully</response>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

I am not sure whether this can be done with via XSLT?

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: A response from what/where? How are you obtaining the text?

Comment: Response from the application which is REST base. I am sorry for not mentioned that too.

Comment: But the response is just plain text? Not XML (or JSON)? If you are using XSLT 2.0, you could use `unparsed-text()` to fetch the message from the URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-xslt20-20011220/#function-unparsed-text

Comment: Yes response is just plane text which really weird. I was wondering if I can dynamically construct the response based on what text response I am getting. The problem is I am using XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send the text in as a parameter to an XSLT stylesheet and produce the desired XML output with the contents of the value specified in the parameter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:param name="message" select="'Data received successfully to XML'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <response><xsl:value-of select="$message"/></response>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

SOAP output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:param name="message"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <SOAP:Header/>
      <SOAP:Body>
        <response>
          <xsl:value-of select="$message"/>
        </response>
      </SOAP:Body>
    </SOAP:Envelope>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you need a well-formed XML document, use the XSLT itself as the input XML to invoke the transform.

Comment: Hi Mads, Thank you for posting the code, however that's the hard coded message inserting of the message. If the response from the back-end gives different message like `Data is corrupted` but since we already defined the message as success it will overwrite the failed message.

Comment: The first example just has the message configured as a default (to aid in testing and demonstrate where the value comes from). You can remove it, as was done in the second example. If you invoke the XSLT and set the parameter value, it will use the value specified in the `message` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for explaination. If even defined the message in parameter. I was wondering if I can do it dynamically based on the text message.